# Need Help for writing an XML Start Element in C# using xmltextWriter

Tags: c#, xml

I write code like this

```
  XmlDocument xdocMulticom = new XmlDocument();
  StringWriter strwMultiXml = new StringWriter();
  XmlTextWriter xmlMultiAirInfo = new XmlTextWriter(strwMultiXml);
  xmlMultiAirInfo.Formatting = Formatting.None;

  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteStartDocument();
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteStartElement("ns", "cancelreservation", "http://www.opentravel.org/ota/2003/05");
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteStartElement("OTA_VehCancelRQ");
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "http://www.opentravel.org/ota/2003/05");
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteAttributeString("Version", "1.002");
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteAttributeString("PrimaryLangID", "EN");
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteAttributeString("ReqRespVersion", "2.001");
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteStartElement("POS");
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteStartElement("Source");
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteStartElement("RequestorID");
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteAttributeString("Type", "4");
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteAttributeString("ID", "F0F4CCE4A9C24355");
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteEndElement();
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteEndElement();
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteEndElement();
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteStartElement("VehCancelRQCore");
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteAttributeString("CancelType", "Cancel");
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteStartElement("UniqueID");
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteAttributeString("Type", "14");
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteAttributeString("ID", "N2169641");
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteStartElement("PersonName");
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteElementString("GivenName", "Sandra");
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteElementString("Surname", "Jhonsan");
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteEndElement();
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteEndElement();                         
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteEndElement();
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteStartElement("VehCancelRQInfo");
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteStartElement("Vendor");
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteAttributeString("Code", "ZR");
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteEndElement();                          
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteEndElement();
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteEndElement();
  xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteEndElement();
  xdocMulticom.LoadXml(strwMultiXml.ToString());
```

which generates output  like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ns:cancelreservation xmlns:ns="http://www.opentravel.org/ota/2003/05">
  <OTA_VehCancelRQ xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/ota/2003/05" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="1.002" PrimaryLangID="EN" ReqRespVersion="2.001">
    <POS>
      <Source>
        <RequestorID Type="4" ID="F0F4CCE4A9C24355" />
      </Source>
    </POS>
    <VehCancelRQCore CancelType="Cancel">
      <UniqueID Type="14" ID="N2169641">
        <PersonName>
          <GivenName>Sandra</GivenName>
          <Surname>Jhonsan</Surname>
        </PersonName>
      </UniqueID>
    </VehCancelRQCore>
    <VehCancelRQInfo>
      <Vendor Code="ZR" />
    </VehCancelRQInfo>
  </OTA_VehCancelRQ>
</ns:cancelreservation>
```

Which is ok to me but i need it to be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ns:cancelreservation>
  <OTA_VehCancelRQ xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/ota/2003/05" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="1.002" PrimaryLangID="EN" ReqRespVersion="2.001">
    <POS>
      <Source>
        <RequestorID Type="4" ID="F0F4CCE4A9C24355" />
      </Source>
    </POS>
    <VehCancelRQCore CancelType="Cancel">
      <UniqueID Type="14" ID="N2169641">
        <PersonName>
          <GivenName>Sandra</GivenName>
          <Surname>Jhonsan</Surname>
        </PersonName>
      </UniqueID>
    </VehCancelRQCore>
    <VehCancelRQInfo>
      <Vendor Code="ZR" />
    </VehCancelRQInfo>
  </OTA_VehCancelRQ>
</ns:cancelreservation>
```

Is there any way to change it?

Comment: Could add some example of what you want and what you are getting? right now it is rather unclear what you are trying to ask.

Comment: hi,actually i need root element without namespace  like  <ns:cancelreservation>  and rest of xml will be same

Comment: @Sandra That would be invalid XML. The element name can't have a namespace prefix if it doesn't have a namespace.

Comment: Is having the namespace declaration on the ns:cancelreservation actually causing a problem for you?  As far as I can tell from your comments on Spawn's answer, it should be fine that way, and that is the way it should be when you are generating it on its own.

Answer (score 0):

As I See, difference only in namespace in first node... (or it's my mistake?)

Replace this line:

```cs
xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteStartElement("ns", "cancelreservation", "http://www.opentravel.org/ota/2003/05");
```

with this.

```cs
xmlMultiAirInfo.WriteStartElement("ns", "cancelreservation", "");
```

Well, C# is doing all right. Because your element doesn't know about such prefix.
In your sample, "cancelreservation" is not the root element, but if it will be root, xmlns attribute must be present.

Comment: hi,yes this is only diff. but when i write like you..it generate o/p like

Comment: Hi,yes u r right..only diff as u see.. but it will generate o/p like      .....<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><cancelreservation> which is not desired

Comment: and i in trouble bcz day after tommarow is delevery day

Comment: hi..i want to create a soap like this  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
  <soapenv:Header />
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns:CancelReservation>
      <OTA_VehCancelRQ xmlns="......  which is done but only prob in creating root <ns:CancelReservation>

Comment: Well, C# is doing all right. Because your element doesn't know about such prefix. In your sample, "cancelreservation" is not the root element, but if it will be root, xmlns attribute must be present. Also  edited in Answer.

Comment: so plz suggest to create soap like   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"; xmlns:ns="opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">; <soapenv:Header /> <soapenv:Body> <ns:CancelReservation> <OTA_VehCancelRQ xmlns="............. i mean is it posible from webservice etc.. bcz we are third party developer and have only url of soap